# How/when to remove Firebase Auth listener after registration & write to database?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase email/password authentication and writing a username and other information to my database. To write to DB I'm using the auth listener as recommended in the documentation:

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
// ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I log the user out, then log back in the listener fires again and overwrites my database information. So I'm trying to figure out how to remove the listener after it fires the first time.

I've tried the to remove the listener using:

```
Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(listener)
```

But this removes the listener before it has time to write to my database.

This may be simple, but how can I write this to delay removing the listener until after it fires the first time writing to the database?

I've tried in a few places, and I've looked for some alternatives, but I haven't seen anything that solves this which was surprising to me as it seems this would be a very common situation.

Here is the code I'm using to create the account and write to the database:

```
@IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

validate()
if usernameTakenLabel.isHidden == false {
    nextButton.isEnabled = false
}


// Create Account w/ email

let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
let usernamesRef = 
Database.database().reference().child("usernameRef")

if username != "" && email != "" && password != "" {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in
        print("New User successfully created")
    }

    self.listener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {

            //Write username to the database
            usersRef.child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
            usernamesRef.childByAutoId().setValue(username)
            print("username successfully created")
        }
    }
    //PROBLEM:
    //How can I delay this until after the code above runs?

    Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(listener!)
}
}
```

Any and all help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a completion block , whenever the task gets completed then we can call further method.

```
func checkUser(completion:() -> Void)

{

    // Create Account w/ email
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    let usernamesRef =
        Database.database().reference().child("usernameRef")

    if username != "" && email != "" && password != "" {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in
            print("New User successfully created")
        }

        self.listener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {

                //Write username to the database
                usersRef.child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
                usernamesRef.childByAutoId().setValue(username)
                print("username successfully created")

                //call this whenever the the task is completed
                completion()

            }
        }

        //you can also call this function here
        //Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(listener!)
    }

}

checkUser
    {
    print("task Completed")
    Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(listener!)
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, I'm still understanding completion blocks, so thanks!